# W3 CSS : Center Cards within Row

Tags: html, css, row, center, w3.css

I am working within the W3.CSS framework and trying to center two Cards as seen in the following image.

[image]

When the viewport is large or medium sized, I would like the cards to sit adjacent to one another. On small viewports, I would like for them to stack one on top of the other. Anyway, try as I might, I just cannot achieve this layout. I am either able to get the cards to sit adjacent to one another, but they will not center within the row, or I get them to be centered, but they stack on top of each other regardless of the size of the viewport.

Here is some sample code as a starting point.

```
 <div class="w3-row w3-padding w3-border w3-gray" style="margin:auto">
    <div class="w3-card" style="width:35%;">
        <p>w3-card</p>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-card" style="width:35%;">
        <p>w3-card</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried so many different approaches to achieve the desired structure using Grid, Layout and Display controls, but NOTHING has worked.

Thanks in advance for tips or a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty basic way of doing it by setting them to inline-block and also setting them to have a min-width in px so they will truncate down when the screen gets small.  Here's the jsfiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/trw530q1/

```css
.w3-card {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.w3-gray {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-row w3-padding w3-border w3-gray" style="margin:auto">
    <div class="w3-card" style="width:35%;">
        <p>w3-card</p>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-card" style="width:35%;">
        <p>w3-card</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added a bit of bottom margin to the cards so that they have a little space between them when stacked, but your solution was simple and elegant. Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="w3-padding-large w3-border w3-gray">
<div class="w3-cell-row w3-content" style="width:70.5%">
    <div class="w3-cell w3-mobile w3-container w3-card w3-blue">
        <p>w3-card</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-cell w3-mobile" style="padding:0.1em"></div>
    <div class="w3-cell w3-mobile w3-container w3-card w3-blue">
        <p>w3-card</p>
    </div>
</div>    
</div>
```

(Note:The cell in the middle is just for "esthetics". The value of 70.5 is arbitrary because is including this extra cell.)

Comment: I went with the first answer, but yours works very well too. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok. Just remember to rename the modified classes for avoid "collaterals effects" ;-)